# How to distinguish between limited video and members only video

Tags: youtube-data-api

I want distinguish between limited and members video using a YouTube Data APIs 'Video' information.
But those video has same privacy status that "unlisted".

Is there other keys to dintinguish it?

Comment: The YouTube Data API does not define/specify any of these concepts: *limited video* and *member video*.

Comment: @stvar thank you for comment. I understood.